# Update flag for multiple/single, but max date for one ID only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have record as given below

| RowID | RefId | FId | CId | TDateTime | NoOfRec | LastRecFlag | MainId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-21 00:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 2 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-21 12:58:49.000 | NULL | NULL | 55279 |
| 3 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 00:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 4 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 08:33:43.000 | NULL | NULL | 55288 |
| 5 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55269 |
| 6 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55270 |
| 7 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55280 |
| 8 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55284 |

Can any one please help to set LastRecFlag as true only when TDateTime is max in whole day but only for one record having max datetime whose Tdatetime is max. There can be multiple records for a day. And the task can be set for future as well. It will set future time as 9:00:00 for all future related records. After This time passes, If I try to make entry. It takes current time. If current time is max then future related record which is having 9:00:00 time then it will work fine. Because max datetime is the record for the day where time is max then future datetime. Here, I can't set it based on max MainId for the day. Because future related entry is done on current date. And when the actual day comes with that future related date. User can also insert data with current datetime. If it is before future datetime then it is latest record. So MainId will be greater. However it is not the last record. Here, Max Tdatetime should be based on RefId. Can anyone please please suggest something for this issue. I'm tired of
thinking about the solution for this.

Expected result:

| RowID | RefId | FId | CId | TDateTime | NoOfRec | LastRecFlag | MainId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-21 00:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 2 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-21 12:58:49.000 | 2 | 1 | 55279 |
| 3 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 00:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 4 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 08:33:43.000 | 6 | NULL | 55288 |
| 5 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55269 |
| 6 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55270 |
| 7 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 55280 |
| 8 | 7532 | 159 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | 1 | 55284 |

Actual result:

| RowID | RefId | FId | CId | TDateTime | NoOfRec | LastRecFlag | MainId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-21 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-21 12:58:49.000 | 2 | 1 | 55279 |
| 3 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-22 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-22 08:33:43.000 | 6 | 0 | 55288 |
| 5 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 55269 |
| 6 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 55270 |
| 7 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 55280 |
| 8 | 7532 | 9 | 777 | 2023-02-22 09:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 | 55284 |

```
UPDATE f
SET f.NoOfRec = t.NoOfRec,
    f.LastRecFlag = CASE 
                        WHEN f.TDateTime = t.MaxTDateTime 
                            THEN 1  
                            ELSE 0 
                    END
FROM #Final AS f
JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS NoOfRec, RefId,
            CAST(TDateTime AS Date) AS TDateTime,
            MAX(TDateTime) AS MaxTDateTime,
            MAX(ISNULL(MainId, 0)) AS MainId
     FROM #FinalResult
     GROUP BY RedId, CAST(TDateTime AS Date))t ON f.RefId = t.RefId 
                                               AND ISNULL(f.MainId, 0) = t.MainId 
                                               AND CAST(f.TDateTime AS Date) = t.TDateTime
```

Comment: Is the "future" logic thing actually relevant in the question or just an aside? If it's not relevant i suggest to remove it because it's confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a simple "Get top 1 from query" select:

```sql
-- Data
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-21 00:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 0)
    ,   (2, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-21 12:58:49.000', NULL, NULL, 55279)
    ,   (3, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-22 00:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 0)
    ,   (4, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-22 08:33:43.000', NULL, NULL, 55288)
    ,   (5, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-22 09:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 55269)
    ,   (6, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-22 09:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 55270)
    ,   (7, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-22 09:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 55280)
    ,   (8, 7532, 159, 777, N'2023-02-22 09:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 55284)
) t (RowID,RefId,FId,CId,TDateTime,NoOfRec,LastRecFlag,MainId)

-- SELECT
SELECT *
,   noofrec = CASE WHEN sortRecCount = 1 THEN NoOfRecNew END
,   LastRecFlag = CASE WHEN sort = 1 THEN 1 END
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY TDateTime DESC, MainID DESC /*tiebreaker??*/) AS sort
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY MainID DESC ) AS sortRecCount
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE)) AS NoOfRecNew
    FROM    #data
    ) t

-- Update
UPDATE  t
SET noofrec = CASE WHEN sortRecCount = 1 THEN NoOfRecNew END
,   LastRecFlag = CASE WHEN sort = 1 THEN 1 END
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY TDateTime DESC, MainID DESC /*tiebreaker??*/) AS sort
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY MainID DESC ) AS sortRecCount
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE)) AS NoOfRecNew
    FROM    #data
    ) t
```

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY TDateTime DESC, MainID DESC /*tiebreaker??*/)` gives us the last time per day sorted by MainID as tiebreaker to assign the LastRecFlag.

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefId, CAST(TDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY MainID DESC ) AS sortRecCount` is similar, but here you want to assign the record count to the highest `MainID`.

The final CASE WHEN ensure that we only set the values where both of the above conditions are = 1, ie, the desired row.

Output:

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your logic on the future time etc. Anyway you can make use of the window function to get the information you need and tweak the logic to suites your requirement. The query below does gives your expected result for the provided sample data. Verify the logic with your data.

```
update t
set   NoOfRec = case when t.LastRec = 1
                     then RecCount
                     end,
      LastRecFlag = case when  t.TDateTime = t.MaxDateTime
                         and   convert(time, MaxDateTime) <> '09:00'
                         then 1
                         else 0
                         end
from  
(
  select *,
         RecCount    = count(*) over (partition by RefId, convert(date, TDateTime)),
         MaxDateTime = max(TDateTime) over (partition by RefId, convert(date, TDateTime)),
         LastRec     = row_number() over (partition by RefId, convert(date, TDateTime)
                                              order by case when convert(time, TDateTime) = '09:00'
                                                            then convert(date, TDateTime)
                                                            else TDateTime
                                                            end desc, 
                                                       MainId desc)
  from   yourtable
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand you future logic, but to get the expected result from your sample data you could use an inner join like this

```
update f
set    f.NoOfRec = case when f.TDateTime = tt.maxdate then tt.reccount else null end,
       f.LastRecFlag = case when f.RowID = tt.maxrowid then 1 else null end
from   final f
  inner join ( 
    select convert(date, f2.TDateTime) as TDate, 
           count(f2.RowID) as reccount, 
           max( case when datepart(hour, f2.TDateTime) <> 9
                      and datepart(minute, f2.TDateTime) <> 0 then f2.TDateTime
                     else null end) as maxdate,
           max(RowID) as maxrowid
    from   final f2
    group by convert(date, f2.TDateTime)
  ) tt on f.TDateTime = tt.maxdate or f.RowID = tt.maxrowid
```

See this at work [in this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3DHbqJf2)